# How can I set global charset for Symfony validator?

Tags: php, symfony, character-encoding

I am using [Symfony-Length-Contraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html) several times in my php-project. My Symfony-Version is 2.5.10

Unfortunately, my charset is ISO-8859-1, Symfony-Length-Constraint [defaults to UTF-8](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html#charset).

Well, I can change every @Assert\Length like this:

```
* @Assert\Length(charset="ISO-8859-15")
```

to have validation work probably.

But I want to set this charset globally for my project, instead of setting charset for each Length-Assertion. How/Can I do this?

Comment: Which version of symfony?

Comment: 2.5.10.

In special, this question is related to updating to 2.5.10 (from 2.5.8), as Length-Validator changed it's behavior here, charset related, see https://github.com/nicolas-grekas/symfony/commit/3a9058a7d767b969c587adb488592cad4781ebf5

Answer (score 1):

That is a good question - You can certainly subclass the constraint to achieve this

Assuming 2.6 defaults:

**src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/Length.php**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;

/**
 * @Annotation
 *
 * @api
 */
class Length extends Constraints\Length
{
    public $charset = 'ISO-8859-1';
}
```

Then, in your entity files or wherever

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert;

(...)

* @CustomAssert\Length(min=123)
```

But I'll be honest, I'm not sure if this is the *best* way.

Comment: Well, it is better; but hopefully there is an easier way.